# Getting "Cannot load JDBC Driver Class" error while trying to connect with Database - Jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

In Jmeter, i have entered the database configuration (database URL, JDBC Driver class, username & password) for JDBC connection and also declared variable name of pool in JDBC Request as well. I have also updated the SQL Query and Query type. But, when i run i am getting response message "java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#opt_jdbc):

> You will need to add your database vendor's JDBC driver to the [classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) if you want to do JDBC testing. Make sure the file is a jar file, not a zip.

So you will need to download [MySQL Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) and drop the .jar file to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation. JMeter restart will be required to pick up the .jar

Alternatively you can configure the path to the JDBC .jar in [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level, in this case restart will not be required

[image]

More information: [How to Test MySQL Connection](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mysql-test-connection)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I have incorporated the same suggestion and still have the same error. Please advise.